# UI Bootstrap custom directive controller is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use [UI Bootstrap Collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) in my custom directive `<collapse>`

However, I get this `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CollapseDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qx9xiFQMGXJ0w943v0UW?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ng-controller` from template.
Define controller inline:

```
controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
  }]
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/f8eX5H07QUiBILiDDCy8?p=preview)

Another option is to define controller:

```
.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

and refer to it in directive: `controller: 'CollapseDemoCtrl'`

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BT3cO1UzqBXMB8TEwcrM?p=preview)

Comment: do I really need to define the controller inline? Is there no other way?

Comment: It's all cool, but I don't understand why my approach isn't working. Why won't it pass my controller to the directive?

Comment: You did not define a controller, just added a function.

Comment: can you post the plunk from your comment as an answer, cause this is the one providing an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('myApp.collapse', []);
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'myApp.collapse',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);

(function(){
  'use strict';
  
angular.module('myApp.collapse',[])
.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', CollapseDemoCtrl)
.directive('collapse', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'collapse.html',
      controller: 'CollapseDemoCtrl' 
    };
  });
  function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope){
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
  }

  
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="collapse-module.js"></script>
    <script src="collapse-directive.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <collapse></collapse>
    
  </body>
</html>


<div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
 <hr>
 <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
  <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (function(){
  'use strict';
  
  var app = angular.module('myApp.collapse',[]);
app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', CollapseDemoCtrl);
  app.directive('collapse', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'collapse.html',
      controller: 'CollapseDemoCtrl' 
    };
  });
  function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope){
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
  }

  
})();

Comment: your not define the controller. u need to define like this(app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', CollapseDemoCtrl);)

Comment: old : controller: CollapseDemoCtrl         now  controller: 'CollapseDemoCtrl'

Comment: your answer helped, thank you. Although Artem answered my question most precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp.collapse', []);


angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'myApp.collapse',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);


(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp.collapse').
  directive('collapse',['$http', function($http){
   
   
   
    console.log("Test")
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'collapse.html',
      controller: function ($scope) {
     $scope.isCollapsed = false; 
      }
    }; 
   
}]); 


  
   
  
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="collapse-module.js"></script>
    <script src="collapse-directive.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <collapse></collapse>
    
  </body>
</html>



<div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
 <hr>
 <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
  <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you need '$http'?

Comment: now not need. In future if any json or server call is thr u can use it.

Comment: Ok, but this still doesn't answer the error about the controller function being not a function.